# Decoding signature for verification not working

Tags: solidity, signature, abi, verify, encoding

I'm trying to verify a signature, but when I decode it, the function reverts. This is the function I'm using

```
function source(bytes memory signature) public returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) {
        (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = abi.decode(signature, (bytes32, bytes32, uint8));
    }
```

The encoded signature looks like this (Im encoding it using `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters`) and then making an `eth_call`

```
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041
  8318875f720f88683b75c949a1e83fcefbd586ae8a8276944f126cdba176f384
  4b05c92d1b4393dcf1dad2d59b88f196c9aba988141265bdacbfdbc90049fa21
  1c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But if I hardcode the signature into the contract like this It seems to work

```
function source() public returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) {
    bytes memory signature = "0x8318875F720F88683B75C949A1E83FCEFBD586AE8A8276944F126CDBA176F3844B05C92D1B4393DCF1DAD2D59B88F196C9ABA988141265BDACBFDBC90049FA211c";
    (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = abi.decode(signature, (bytes32, bytes32, uint8));
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on and why it happens this way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The signature has extra data at the beginning (they seems to be an 32 bytes offset, and 32 bytes string length).

Ideally the signature would look like this

```
8318875f720f88683b75c949a1e83fcefbd586ae8a8276944f126cdba176f384
4b05c92d1b4393dcf1dad2d59b88f196c9aba988141265bdacbfdbc90049fa21
1c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you account for the extra data at the beggining and the `v` parameter being left aligned this code should work:

```
function source(bytes memory signature) public returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes1) {
    (uint256 m, uint256 n, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, bytes1 v) = abi.decode(signature, (uint256, uint256, bytes32, bytes32, bytes1));
    return (r, s, v);
}
```